# NetApp Filer queue length?

Tags: netapp

Is there a way to determine how many transactions are pending in the filer?

How many words are required to ask this question before Post button will work?
I'll try another sentence.

Comment: You will need to give a little more information here. Is this a 7 Mode or Cluster Mode filer, is this for disks, volumes etc. Is this for block or file storage?

Comment: Not sure on the first or second question, but it's file storage.  I'll get the other answers.